# E-Commerce on Facebook Apps/Canvas Page

Tags: e-commerce, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

Is it against the Facebook TOS to run an e-commerce app as a Canvas page?  I was reading through the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and I see that there are specific call-outs for Games, and the policy states that Games may only use Facebook Credits.  Are all other applications required to use Facebook Credits as the only acceptable form of payment?  Or, can I use PayPal, Google Checkout, or any other merchant services vendor available out there?  To clarify, I want to be able to do a few things integrated with the FB platform:

- sell products
- provide SaaS solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the Platform Policies and didn't find anything either.

I'm not sure [this](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/04/22/canvas-connect-websites-best/) is a reliable source, but quoting it:

> Canvas Apps can use Facebook Credits as their payment method (and all games must do so as of July 1st, 2011), making payments more accessible, as users may already have a balance of Credits However, Credits come with a 30% tax that goes to Facebook. Non-games can process payments however they want, and do not need to pay Facebook’s tax.

So it seems you can use any other payment gateway. Actually you should, since FBs 30% cut on credits seems like way too much.